# Keystone session cookie only working on localhost

Tags: cookies, next.js, keystonejs

**Edit:**
After investigating this further, it seems cookies *are* sent correctly on *most* API requests. However something happens in the specific request that checks if the user is logged in and it always returns null. When refreshing the browser a successful preflight request is sent and nothing else, even though there is a session and a valid session cookie.

**Original question:**

I have a NextJS frontend authenticating against a Keystone backend.

When running on localhost, I can log in and then refresh the browser without getting logged out, i.e. the browser reads the cookie correctly.

When the application is deployed on an external server, I can still log in, but when refreshing the browser it seems no cookie is found and it is as if I'm logged out. However if I then go to the Keystone admin UI, I am still logged in.

In the browser settings, I can see that for localhost there is a "keystonejs-session" cookie being created. This is not the case for the external server.

Here are the session settings from the Keystone config file.
The value of `process.env.DOMAIN` on the external server would be for example `example.com` when Keystone is deployed to `admin.example.com`. I have also tried `.example.com`, with a leading dot, with the same result. (I believe the leading dot is ignored in newer specifications.)

```
const sessionConfig = {
  maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
  secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
  sameSite: 'lax',
  secure: true,
  domain: process.env.DOMAIN,
  path: "/",
};
const session = statelessSessions(sessionConfig);
```

(The session object is then passed to the config function from @keystone-6/core.)

**Current workaround:**

I'm currently using a workaround which involves routing all API requests to '/api/graphql' and rewriting that request to the real URL using Next's own rewrites. Someone recommended this might work and it does, sort of. When refreshing the browser window the application is still in a logged-out state, but after a second or two the session is validated.

To use this workaround, add the following rewrite directive to next.config.js

```
rewrites: () => [
    {
      source: '/api/graphql',
      destination:
        process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
          ? `http://localhost:3000/api/graphql`
          : process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_ENDPOINT,
    },
  ],
```

Then make sure you use this URL for queries. In my case that's the URL I feed to `createUploadLink()`.

This workaround still means constant error messages in the logs since relative URLs are not supposed to work. I would love to see a proper solution!

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to know what's happening for sure without knowing more about your setup. Inspecting the requests and responses your browser is making may help figure this out. Look in the "network" tab in your browser dev tools. When you make make the request to sign in, you should see the cookie being set in the headers of the response.

Some educated guesses:

**Are you accessing your external server over HTTPS?**

They Keystone docs for the [session API](https://keystonejs.com/docs/apis/session) mention that, when setting `secure` to `true`...

> [...] the cookie is only sent to the server when a request is made with the `https:` scheme (except on `localhost`)

So, if you're running your deployed env over plain HTTP, the cookie is never set, creating the behaviour you're describing. Somewhat confusingly, in development the flag is ignored, allowing it to work.

**A similar thing can happen if you're deploying behind a proxy, like nginx**:

In this scenario, a lot of people choose to have the proxy terminate the TLS connection, so requests are forwarded to the backend over HTTP (but on a private network, so still relatively secure). In that case, you need to do two things:

- Ensure the proxy is configured to forward [the `X-Forwarded-Proto` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-Proto), which informs the backend which protocol was used originally request
- Tell express to trust what the proxy is saying by configuring [the `trust proxy` setting](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#trust.proxy.options.table)

I did [a write up of this proxy issue](https://gist.github.com/molomby/6fa22c165e0025f0f83d55195f3c6e37) a while back. It's for Keystone 5 (so some of the details are off) but, if you're using a reverse proxy, most of it's still relevant.

### Update

From Simons comment, the above guesses missed the mark  but I'll leave them here in case they help others.

> Since posting about this issue a month ago I was actually able to work around it by routing API requests via a relative path like '/api/graphql' and then forwarding that request to the real API on a separate subdomain. For some mysterious reason it works this way.

**This is starting to sound like a CORS or issue**

If you want to serve your front end from a different origin (domain) than the API, the API needs to return a specific header to allow this. Read up on [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. You can configure this setting the `cors` option in the [Keystone server config](https://keystonejs.com/docs/apis/config#server) which Keystone uses to configure the [`cors` package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#configuration-options).

Alternatively, the solution of proxying API requests via the Next app should also work. It's not obvious to me why your proxying "workaround" is experiencing problems.

Comment: Hello! The issue is definitely not one of these, but thank you so much for your detailed answer. Since posting about this issue a month ago I was actually able to work around it by routing API requests via a relative path like '/api/graphql' and then forwarding that request to the real API on a separate subdomain. For some mysterious reason it works this way.

Comment: I have updated my question to describe my current workaround and also specify the problem a bit better. As I mention, cookies *are* in fact sent, but crucially the authentication request is not completed properly. I am only seeing a preflight request and then nothing.